# Is there any report engine in NodeJS (like JasperReport in java)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, report

In java, we have report engines like JasperReport, BIRT, etc.  Is there similar javascript based report engines running under NodeJS?

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: Not yet.

Medium answer: There's a relatively young project on Github aiming to create just that: https://github.com/Nathanaela/fluentreports

Not nearly as mature as JasperReports, but perhaps a starting point.

Answer (score 6):

you can use jsreport nowdays
there is a rendering engine behind it and working grate with a client server architecture
https://jsreport.net/blog/jsreport-and-nodejs

Answer (score 4):

Try with node-jasper, current version 0.2.0

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jasper

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Visualize.js](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/visualizejs-getting-started)?

http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/visualizejs-getting-started

Comment: Problem with that solution is that it requires the JasperServer, thus a Java Servlet container. Doesn't work with NodeJs entirely only.

Answer (score 0):

I usually used jasper report for pdf generation. If you have this purpose only then you can use [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/#/).